# awk + print the second field in line only if the four field is 0

Tags: awk

How to print $2 by awk only if the fourth field is not 0 (zero).

```
line="root     13246 11314  457 15: qsRw -m1"
```

then awk will print 13246, but if

```
line="root     13246 11314  0 15: qsRw -m1"
```

then awk will not print anything

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
awk '{if ($4) print $2;}' < inputfile
```

Answer (score 12):

```
awk '$4!=0{print $2}' file
```

or just

```
awk '$4{print $2}' file
```

The syntax of awk is

```
awk '/pattern/{action}' file
```

the "pattern" part is actually an implicit "if" control flow structure. Therefore you can 
omit putting an "if" keyword.

Comment: Pedantically, the syntax is `awk 'condition {action}'`, and `/pattern/` is a true/false condition.

Comment: That is, `/pattern/` is just one species of `condition`, and not the same species as is used in the first two examples given here (which do exactly what the questioner requested).